# Static assertion failed with "Windows headers require the default packing option..."

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, header-files

When I'm trying to compile my C++ project in Visual Studio, I keep getting the 2 following errors:

```
E1574: Static assertion failed with "Windows headers require the default 
packing option. Changing this can lead to memory corruption. This diagnostic 
can be disabled by building with WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH defined."
```

and

```
C2338: Windows headers require the default packing option. Changing this can 
lead to memory corruption. This diagnostic can be disabled by building with 
WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH defined.
```

I think the issue has to be something in my Visual Studio settings, cause the project compiles fine on my other PC, and I just installed Visual Studio on this PC.

From doing some searches look like the issue stems from a mismatch of Windows packages, however when installing Visual Studio I tried to install all the C++ and Windows 10 modules I saw.

Also, I'm only including `windows.h` in order to use `ShellExecute()`, so if there's a better way to use `ShellExecute()` I'm open to that. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the `/Zp` (structure packing) compiler option.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks that seems to work! Any drawbacks to that method?

Comment: The real question is why did you add `/Zp` in the 1st place?

Comment: @RichardCritten Working off an SDK project template so it was enabled by default.

Comment: Most unusual; which one? I have never seen any of the builtin ones set that flag.

Comment: @RichardCritten super specific, the Adobe After Effects Plugin SDK, Struct Member Alignment is set to `4 Byte (/Zp4)`

Comment: @JustinTaylor -- Then whoever put together that package is woefully not paying attention.  There are ways to set the packing for custom structs in the source code itself (things like `pragma pack`), and not by a universal compiler switch that screws up your other structs.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will watch out for that in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As 1201ProgramAlarm mentioned above, the solution was disabling the `/Zp` (structure packing) compiler option.

Comment: Where exactly in MSVC can I disable this? I searched around, but did not find anything helpful yet :/

Comment: @LilaQ go to Project Settings > C/C++ > Code Generation > Struct Member Alignment (change to Default)

Comment: Did not work for me. Problem is still there without the compiler option /Zp. I'm using Platform Toolset v142. Interestingly, I had no issues with v141.

Answer (score 1):

If others arrive at this question (like I did), the underlaying issue is, bar the project compiler options doing it as per the comment by
code4days, possibly that some source file or header is fiddling with the struct packing size before the windows.h is included.

In your sources and headers, look for

```
#pragma pack(push, ...
```

If you can, move this to where the structs are actually defined and move the corresponding `#pragma pack(pop)` under the stucts.

In any case, by not having that `#prama pack(push, 1)` just before the windows.h include fixed the compiler error for me.