# Default/boilerplate code gives me error in Visual Studio 2017. E1574. Unreal. But Build Succeeded

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I am trying to learn UE4, but currently I am stuck doing something really simple. I want to create a Breakout style 'Paddle' as a blueprint.

But I have strange problem where my code looks good to me (and I am copying the code directly from a tutor video) but in Visual Studio I get **error: E1574 static assertion failed with "TAtomic is only usable with trivial types"**. I even deleted all my code and just left it back with the default code that UE4 provides (when I clicked 'Create C++ Class > Actor'). The error still persists when building that.

The other problem I get is that the 'details' panel in my Paddle_BP is empty for the StaticMeshComponent that I instantiated in my code. In the tutorial, it provides a StaticMeshComponent where you can choose a mesh, add physics and other options.

Here is my code:

**Paddle.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Paddle.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class SHIT_PONG_CPP_API APaddle : public AActor
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
// Sets default values for this actor's properties
APaddle();

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "ActorMeshComponents")
UStaticMeshComponent* StaticMesh;

protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
// Called every frame
virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

**Paddle.cpp**

```
#include "Paddle.h"

// Sets default values
APaddle::APaddle()
{  
// Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

StaticMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("CustomStaticMesh"));

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APaddle::BeginPlay()
{
Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APaddle::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{ 
Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}
```

I have read this thread ([Static assertion failed with "Windows headers require the default packing option..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570681/static-assertion-failed-with-windows-headers-require-the-default-packing-option)) and page from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=vs-2019) about changing the compiler settings. But the instructions seem to be out of date I cannot find "Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation" in my options at all.

Comment: Hmm ... minus one and no comment.... good work whoever that was

Comment: always use version control when doing c++ with unreal. I remember I write a bad code that caused my blueprint to become corrupted and engine would crash every time I tried to open it even after I redo all bad code. I had to look into backups to recover some of the work. but now with version control every time I mess up something I can go back to previous change without any problem.

Comment: I recommend [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) for version control. Anyways, Try deleting Intermediate files and rebuild.

Comment: thank  you. I did have VCS set up with Unity and also my old projects in raw code. So I should be able to manage that. Cheers

Comment: I am getting this error on a new project also

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs when you build within Visual Studio. I think you will avoid this error if you compile from within the UE environment. Here is a link from the Unreal Forum which suggests the same solution: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1703131-error-static-assertion-failed-with-tatomic-is-only-usable-with-trivial-types