# ERROR Windows headers require the default packing option on winnt.h

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2019

I have an old C++ program I recovered to update and re-use it with Visual Studio 2019.

When I try to compile `winnt.h`, it gives the error:

> Windows headers require the default packing option. Changing this can lead to memory corruption. This diagnosis can be disabled by building with WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH defined

I saw this post [Static assertion failed with "Windows headers require the default packing option..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570681/) and I already changed the packing option from 4bytes to default (*Project Settings > C/C++ > Code Generation > Struct Member Alignment (change to Default)*).

What am I missing? How can I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps you have a `#pragma pack` directive somewhere that isn't pushing and popping the value correctly. I just changed the packing to 4 in my project, received the error, then changed back to default and it went away. *shrug* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-160

Comment: Also, make sure you changed the project setting for the same configuration that you are building (or, better, for all configurations / all platforms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if `#pragma pack` is used in the code. If you use `#pragma pack`, do not set `Struct Member Alignment` in the project configuration, because it will disturb the direct alignment of other code.
2. Check whether your project platform settings are consistent with the property page settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `#pragma pack`, as long as you use it *correctly* (ie, using `push`/`pop` pairs)

Comment: @Retired Ninja @dxiv @Barrnet Chou @Remy Lebeau Thank you for your answers. Yes, code uses `pragma pack` 2 times. This is a rfactor 2 plugin, you download 2 headers and then you program the source to do what you want with the data extracted. I've seen they use `pragma` in both headers. At the begining `#pragma pack( push, 4 )` and at the end `#pragma pack( pop )` on both codes. I'm really new on C++ so I don't really know how they work, but I'm gonna try to solve with all your advices. I'll let you know what worked. Thank you!

Comment: `#pragma pack` was ok. Problem came from the property page settings. Despite I corrected the packing option from 4 bytes to default it was only done on **All configurations**, when I checked **Debug** and **Realase** it was not. Once corrected this program compiled. Thank you to everybody!